# Is there a Struts 2 Eclipse plugin that will create a new action class and map it?

Tags: struts2, eclipse-plugin

My question is if it exists a plugin on eclipse to create a new action class and map it in `struts.xml` file automatically? Also could be convenient if the name of the action class was changed, the `struts.xml` file changes.

Answer (score 0):

no but it's possible in myeclipse

Comment: It would be good to add some additional information about *how* to do this in MyEclipse; just saying "it's possible" may be correct but it isn't as helpful as it could be

Comment: Sorry i just saw a friend work with it there is a graphical plugin already installed with myEclipse you just draw your action and the result and the xml will be generated. I'm sorry that's all what i know